# Where do I find the default settings for my app in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**Problem:** `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested settings, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.`

**Example solution from Django Docs:**

```
# Put this before accessing settings
from django.conf import settings

if not settings.configured:
      settings.configure(default_settings=myapp_defaults, DEBUG=True)
```

Okay but, where do I find my app's default settings?

**My file structure is:**

[image]

Comment: Could it be just `settings.configure(default_settings=charges.settings, DEBUG=True)`?

Comment: `charges` is not a variable or python file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is simply because of not telling Django which setting file it should use.as i see that there are little ambiguities about what to do facing this error a list different solution you can take.

there are 3 different ways to handle this problem.

1- define a environment variable in the operating system([link](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)).

2- if you are using a virtual environment; set a new environment variable in activate.bat

```
 set "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=charges.settings"
```

3- (the way you did!)in each python file; write the command which defines that environment variable.

```
 os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'charges.settings')
```

but if use this method it is really important where you are putting that command(in the second and definitely first case we don't care at all!).
so you should take care of not using django before that command.

Comment: Yeah, too much of a hassle. I switched to FastAPI

Answer (score 1):

By screenshot looks like you’re using PyCharm.

Do right click on the “second” `charges` from the screenshot and click on option “mark as sources root”

Then you’ll be be able to do what @raphael mentioned in the comment

Your settings are located under `Charges/charges/charges/settings.py`

Your interpreter does not see it because root is in Charges. Though, it should be also on `Charges/charges` to be able to import settings from it

Answer (score 0):

When you run Django through `python manage.py runserver`, your main project code (charges) is started and the settings.py is loaded. There, you should configure it globally. This default settings can be changed using env variables (if it sits somewhere else, or you want to try another settings.py file).

For your app/modules: create a settings.py and define your default there, then load in the apps.py the settings file like you did. Anyway, default would be overriden by your main settings.py

https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/topics/settings/#custom-default-settings